# socket io working some times after doing load balancing using nginx in my nodejs express web app

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io

I am working with a node js express app. Having admin side and user side. I have used socket io to send alert to the admin whenever a user places an order.
after doing load balancing using Nginx, only alerts are showing sometimes. I understand that it is because the user and admin are connected to different instances (amazon ec2). alerts send to admin only when both are in the same instance(amazon ec2).
what is the better solution to use socket io in this scenario?[socket io connection with express[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqKVv.png)

[nginx configuration for load balancing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjMOB.png)

In browser, console shows the following:
failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
status code: 400

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got it clear but I do configuration like this

```
upstream socket {
     ip_hash;
     server localhost:xxxx; // your instance port
}
```

I decide to create socket path like: { path:"/user-socket" } inside socket configurations

```
location /user-socket {
    proxy_pass http://socket;
}
```